# how to change the color of one portion of an image to another portion of the same image using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, rgb

I have a color image. The image consists of an object which has a shadow. I have removed the shadow but the shadow portion's color is not similar with the background color .Now how can I match the color using MATLAB coding?

Comment: Do you have access to shadow pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the matlab matrix (here called IMG) that corresponds to your image. For example, say that you changed the pixels of the shadows to -20.
Than you can get their indexes doing

`indexes = (IMG == -20)`

To change those values to the background color, assumed equals 100 for example, you set than doing

`IMG(indexes) = 100`

Since you're working with color images, you will need to do this for all the three color matrices that corresponds to your image. In this case you will have a background color for each layer, than you just repeat the process

`indexes1 = (IMG(:, :, 1) == shadow_color_layer_1)`

`indexes2 = (IMG(:, :, 2) == shadow_color_layer_2)`

`indexes3 = (IMG(:, :, 3) == shadow_color_layer_3)`

`IMG(indexes,1) = background_color_layer_1`

`IMG(indexes,2) = background_color_layer_2`

`IMG(indexes,3) = background_color_layer_3`

Comment: but how can I get the shadow_color_layers and Background_color_layers?

Comment: look at the matrix, open it and visualize it with imshow() or another more appropriate method. You should visualize layer by layer. Do you want your method to automatically find the background and replace the shadows? If this is your case, it would be more difficult to do that.